# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null during Page Load

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

My `ViewClass` controller has a method that fetches the data from a Web API based on `Id` and `ClassName`. Now during "page-load" in my model pop-up, I want to display a video using `@Model.ClassVideoUrl` but I get an error instead.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(string Id, string ClassName)
{
    await ViewMyClass(rowId,section);
    return View();
}

private async Task<bool> ViewMyClass(string Id,string ClassName)
{
     //My Code executes fine all data fetch
     return true;
}
```

My `.cshtml` view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#videoDialog').modal('show');
    var video = document.getElementById('myLectVideo');
    video.src = '@Model.ClassVideoUrl';
    video.play();
});
```

How can I display the video in my model pop-up?

**Solution**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync(int rowId, string section)
{
// Fetch Data
return View(videoInfo);
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to be passing any data into the view, how are you expecting to display non-existent data? Also, how does your model look like?

Comment: @Loupeznik You are right thanks for the suggestion. In ` return View(MyModel)`, I just forget to specify my model.